Template Expressions x 'dependsOn' or 'condition'
As some of you know in Azure Pipelines we can include a 'dependsOn' clause on jobs and stages along with a 'condition' so we can dynamically run stages and jobs depending on some values or variables from the running pipeline.
But we can also set template expressions to do almost the same thing.
Here's an example with a stage set up with a template expression.
stages:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'development') }}:
      - stage: Deploy
        dependsOn: Build
        displayName: "Deploying to development environment."
        jobs:
          - deployment:
            environment: MyEnvironment
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                      inputs:
                        ConnectionType: "AzureRM"
                        azureSubscription: "MySubscription"
                        appType: webAppContainer
                        WebAppName: $(environmentName)
                        DockerNamespace: $(ContainerRegistry)
                        DockerRepository: appRepo
                        DockerImageTag: development-$(Build.BuildId)

And here an example of a stage that runs under a condition:
- stage: DeployHomolog
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev'))
    displayName: "Deploying to Homolog Environment"
    jobs:
      - deployment:
        environment: MyEnvironment
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                  inputs:
                    ConnectionType: "AzureRM"
                    azureSubscription: "MySubscription"
                    appType: webAppContainer
                    WebAppName: WebApp
                    DockerNamespace: $(acr)
                    DockerRepository: appRepo
                    DockerImageTag: dev-$(Build.BuildId)

And the question is: What are the pros and cons of each of them? Which of them you prefer using on pipelines?

There is an important difference between template expressions and conditions:

Template expressions get processed at compile time, before the pipeline runs
Conditions are evaluated at runtime to determine whether to start a stage, job, or step

Having that in mind, it's not always a matter of preference - some examples:

You must use job status functions in conditions because there is absolutely no way to know if a job failed or not at compile time.
Variable Build.SourceBranchName is available in templates but
variable Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName is not, so you must use
it in conditions (see column "Available in templates?" in the documentation)
When you add a variable with task.setvariable you can only use it in conditions

Regarding the scenarios where you can use both, my personal preference goes to the template expressions. I prefer not to see a bunch of skipped stages/jobs/steps when I run a build.

I'm looking for knowing when using each one of them because of the same exact thing... I rather see some failed steps or stages than skipped ones.

@GabrielAntonio in the cases you can use both, it's basically a matter of preference. I prefer template expressions but for example one of my ex team members preferred conditions.

@GabrielAntonio not sure if I understand what you mean by "failed steps"? If a condition evaluates to false the correspondent stage/job/task will not run, i.e. it will be skipped.

@Gabriel Antonio
It depends on used cases and complexity, if the above is a single pipeline file (azure-pipeline.yml) implementation, condition is straight forward to use.
In a more complex implementation, using modular templates (having your pipeline calling different templated pipelines), template expressions can help build dynamic, reusable, and flexible templates.
check out TheYAMLPipelineOne

Template expressions allow you to create reusable configurations and handle complex logic dynamically.  You can use complex logic to dynamically include or exclude stages based on variables, making your pipeline highly adaptable.
Using dependsOn with condition is more straightforward and easier to set up. This method is simpler to understand and manage, especially for smaller pipelines. However, it isn't as flexible for handling intricate conditions.
The two methods have their own advantages, and which one to use can be determined based on specific needs. For simpler pipelines, dependsOn with condition works just fine.
